# .net core connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, .net-core

I have a issue here for the connect mysql.
I have a vps that contain mysql server have a database name is 'tuyendungbg'. it's had table and data in there. But when i'm connect and query to select data, that have error for 'Table 'tuyendungbg.Careers' doesn't exist'.

[image: this is my database and data here]

[image: it's error]

here is my controller :

```
  [HttpGet("/nganh-nghe/{slug?}")]
        public IActionResult Index(string slug, [FromQuery(Name =
```

"p")] int currentPage, int
pageSize)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(slug))
{
var career = _context.Careers.FirstOrDefault(x =>
x.Slug.Equals(slug));
if (career != null)
{
ViewBag.CareerName = career.CareerName;

```
                    //var qr = _context.Careers.ToList();
                    var qr = (from p in 
_context.CompanyCareers.Where(x => x.CareerId == 
     career.ID)
                              from b in _context.Companies.Where(x => 
x.Id == p.CompanyId)
                              from i in 
_context.IndustrialAreas.Where(x => x.ID == 
     b.IndustrialAreaId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new CompanyModelView()
                              {
                                  Id = b.Id,
                                  CompanyName = b.CompanyName,
                                  BasicSalary = b.BasicSalary,
                                  Allowance = b.Allowance,
                                  DateCreate = b.DateCreate,
                                  JobTitle = b.JobTitle,
                                  Src = b.Src,
                                  _IndustrialArea = i,
                                  Address = b.Address,
                                  Slug = b.Slug,
                                  WorkTypes = (from tc in 
_context.CompanyWorkTypes.Where(x => 
  x.CompanyId == b.Id)
                                               from type in 
_context.WorkTypes.Where(x => x.Id 
   == 
  tc.TypeId)
                                               select type)
                              }
                    ).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreate).ToList();
                    // var worktype = (from w in 
_context.CompanyWorkTypes.Where(x => 
  x.CompanyId 
                    == qr.))
                    var totalCate = qr.Count();
                    if (pageSize <= 0) pageSize = 10;
                    int countPages = 
(int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalCate / pageSize);

                    if (currentPage > countPages)
                        currentPage = countPages;
                    if (currentPage < 1)
                        currentPage = 1;

                    var pagingModel = new PagingModel()
                    {
                        countpages = countPages,
                        currentpage = currentPage,
                        generateUrl = (pageNumber) => 
Url.Action(nameof(Index), new
                        {
                            p = pageNumber,
                            pageSize = pageSize
                        })
                    };

                    ViewBag.pagingModel = pagingModel;
                    ViewBag.totalPost = totalCate;
                    ViewBag.cateIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;

                    var companies = qr.Skip((currentPage - 1) * 
pageSize)
                                .Take(pageSize).ToList();

                    ViewBag.JobCount = companies.Count();

                    //Set slider menu
                    var leftSlider = new LeftSliderModel()
                    {
                        Areas = new SelectList(_context.Areas, 
nameof(Area.ID), 
                        nameof(Area.NameArea)),
                        Careers = new SelectList(_context.Careers, 
nameof(Career.ID), 
                       nameof(Career.CareerName)),
                        WorkTypes = _context.WorkTypes.ToList(),
                        Experiences = _context.Experiences.ToList()
                    };
                    ViewBag.LeftSlider = leftSlider;

                    return View(companies);
                }
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
```

Comment: are you using database first approach?

Comment: yes. so now i can't select it also it have data

Comment: isnt the table name case sensitive?